# Placing $18$ numbered teams into $3$ groups.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

### Problem

There are $18$ football teams. Each of them randomly gets placed into $3$ possible groups
such that each group contains exactly $6$ teams. The teams are numbered from $i = 1, \ldots,18$.

Without loss of generality consider group $1$.
Let $X_{\min}$ be a random variable which maps group $1$ to the lowest team number contained in it.

Find the distribution of $X_{\min}$.

### Approach

Let's look at an example: Denote group $1$ as $G_1$ and say $G_1 = \{8,4,3,9,5,12\}$. The smallest number in this set is $3$. We can easily observe that $X_\min = 3$ if and only if all teams with numbers $k < 3$ were assigned to either group $2$ or group $3$.

Let $A_i$ be the event that team $i$ gets assigned to group $1$. Obviously $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{3}$.
Then the probability that some team $i$ *does not* get assigned to group $1$ is $P(\overline{A_i}) = 1 - P(A_i) = \frac{2}{3}$.

So in general we get
$$
    P(X_\min = k) = P(A_k \cap \overline{A_{k-1}} \cap \cdots )
$$

My question: can we write $P(X_\min = k) = P(A_k) \cdot P(\overline{A_{k-1}}) \cdot \ldots$

If not (which I think), how can I calculate this probability?

Maybe looking at arbitrary sets $\{k, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6\}$, then choosing $5$ numbers from the remaining upper $18-k$ numbers to get all such $\binom{18 - k}{5}$ sets, so we are left with the binomial distribution:
$$
    P(X_\min = k) = \binom{18 - k}{5} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^1 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5
$$

I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the same as: you pick 6 different numbers from $1, 2, \ldots, 18$ and find the distribution of the smallest?

So $$\Pr(X_\min = k) = \frac{{18-k \choose 5}}{{18 \choose 6}}, \forall 1\leqslant k \leqslant 13.$$

Comment: Seems to make more sense. I just calculated it with my result and it doesn't even give me something in $[0,1]$ lol

Comment: Right, it's always good to check numerically. I made sure my numbers add up to 1 before I posted my answer.

Comment: Can we somehow derive this equation from the events $A_i$? It seems reasonable but I want it to have some connection to the elemental events here.

Comment: Probably, but I personally think it's gonna be messy,  and probably not worth doing.  I could be wrong.